# Styling GeoJson in leaflet according to attributes

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am serously stuck with a little error I cannot interpret. I hope you can help me. I am trying to style my geojson polygon layer according to attributes in leaftlet and am getting this error:

Object {type: "FeatureCollection", crs: Object, features: Array[49]}.

This is my code:

```
function getVictimsColor(totalone){
if (totalone > 1000){
    return 'red';
}else if(totalone > 500){
    return 'orange'
}else if(totalone > 250){
    return 'blue'
}else if(totalone > 100){
    return 'white'
}else if(totalone > 50){
    return 'green'
}else if(totalone > 10){
    return 'black'
}else if(totalone > 5){
    return 'yellow'
}


}

 function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: getVictimsColor(feature.properties.totalone)
        }; 
    }
var map = L.map('map').setView([47.9630, 24.1875], 4);
var layer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>  
layer.addTo(map);

function addDataToMap(data, map) {
var dataLayer = L.geoJson(
data,
{style:getVictimsColor}
);
dataLayer.addTo(map);
}

$.getJSON("Europe_victims.geojson", function(data) {
console.log(data)
addDataToMap(data, map); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came across this.

In:

```
function addDataToMap(data, map) {
  var dataLayer = L.geoJson(
    data,
    { style:getVictimsColor }
  );
  dataLayer.addTo(map);
}
```

change `style:getVictimsColor` to `style: style`

Should work (?)

Answer (score 0):

The "error" you report is probably just the result of your `console.log(data)`.

Leaflet probably does not understand how to render your GeoJSON data because you give your `getVictimsColor` function to the `style` option of the `L.geoJson` constructor, instead of giving it your `style` function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I took console.log out and the error is gone but however it would still not style the layer...